# How to reject input with a certain symbol in it before parsing it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm writing a small mathematical game where sums are generated, and when answered, scored and then another sum is generated. The program is, as of an hour or so ago, flawless but for one thing; the program crashes if the user attempts to input anything that contains more than numbers (with the exception of putting a - before the numbers, for a negative value). Here is my current code for parsing input (I may be using that terminology wrong; if so, I'm sorry):

```
private void txtAnswer_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // If a press of the enter key is detected... 
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            // The player's answer is converted to an integer and checked against the correct answer. 
            userguess = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtAnswer.Text);

            if (userguess == answer)
            {
                // If the player's answer is correct, an appropriate message is displayed and 1 point added to the kill-score. 
                lblResult.Text = "# Enemy charge calculated correctly, charge bounced back and damage evaded.";
                lblRight.Text = (System.Convert.ToInt32(lblRight.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // If the player's answer is incorrect, an appropriate message is displayed and 100 points are added to the damages cost counter. 
                lblResult.Text = "# Enemy charge calculated incorrectly, charge fired and hit! The charge had " + answer.ToString() + " power units applied.";
                lblWrong.Text = (System.Convert.ToInt32(lblWrong.Text) + 100).ToString();
            }
            // After appropriate action has been taken based on the player's answer, a new sum is generated. 
            makeNewSum();
        }
    }
```

I'm not that advanced of a coder, and I've no idea how I can get it to check what is actually being submitted before allowing it through and crashing if it's bad. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: See [User input validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx). Or the equivalent for WPF. Or, if you want to be less formal, change your `Convert.Int32` so you use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: @JimMischel, I may be mistaken but doesn't TryParse() has issues with negative numbers?

Comment: @maccettura: Not that I'm aware of. `TryParse` works just fine with negative numbers. Can you show me an example that illustrates those supposed "issues?"

Comment: I have no examples, it was just something I thought I knew.  Upon further research I have found that I was in error.  I removed my submission and fully agree TryParse() is the way to go.

Comment: I couldn't get TryParse() to work... It doesn't matter anymore, neoistheone gave me the perfect solution, but thanks anyway guys.

Comment: @Ultra: The solution of neo *is* using `TryParse`...

Comment: @Daniel I should have been more specific; I was referring to paqo's method. It's 4am in the morning here, my mind and thus my typing are not at their best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a character for example can't be converted to `Int32`, change this:

```
userguess = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtAnswer.Text);
```

to this:

```
if (!int.TryParse(txtAnswer.Text, out userguess)) { return; }
```

If it succeeds then it will set the integer value to `userguess` so the remainder of the program can stay the same.

Comment: This answer was simpler and made much more sense to someone with less coding experience than the others. This is exactly what I needed, and I don't even have to ask about how it works because I can actually tell. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. :) But how about an upvote for a technically correct answer?

Comment: Also fair enough :P I couldn't get your method to work, but that might because it's early morning and I'm not thinking straight. I can see some of the logic in your method and I'll credit you for that :)

Comment: Thanks!  I did have a syntax error on the first edit. @Daniel Hilgarth straightened me out tho.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int userguess;
if (int.TryParse(txtAnswer.Text, out userguess))
{
        if (userguess == answer)
        {
            // If the player's answer is correct, an appropriate message is displayed and 1 point added to the kill-score. 
            lblResult.Text = "# Enemy charge calculated correctly, charge bounced back and damage evaded.";
            lblRight.Text = (System.Convert.ToInt32(lblRight.Text) + 1).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // If the player's answer is incorrect, an appropriate message is displayed and 100 points are added to the damages cost counter. 
            lblResult.Text = "# Enemy charge calculated incorrectly, charge fired and hit! The charge had " + answer.ToString() + " power units applied.";
            lblWrong.Text = (System.Convert.ToInt32(lblWrong.Text) + 100).ToString();
        }
        // After appropriate action has been taken based on the player's answer, a new sum is generated. 
        makeNewSum();               
}
else{
    lblResult.Text = "Incorrect value!";
}
```

`TryParse` will attempt to parse your text value and put the result in userguess.  If it succeeds it returns true, if it fails it returns false.

Comment: you are missing the declaration of the `userguess` variable and an `out` modifier before it in the call to `TryParse`.